# Can I make a simple distribution amp with a CD4050 hex buffer IC?

Tags: amplifier, buffer

I've got a 555 circuit hooked up to a Stylophone-type keyboard. I'd like to duplicate the audio tones—which I assume are square waves (coming out of pin 3)—a couple of times and run them through an octave-up circuit and frequency divider, and then on to a mixing circuit and see if I can get the tones to be more complex and chord-like.

I've seen the bare-bones distribution amp circuit on this site ([Active audio splitter (Line levels)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266872/active-audio-splitter-line-levels)) comprised of op amps. But, I found this [PRL-414B](https://www.pulseresearchlab.com/products/prl-414b?variant=40597758115955) diagram online and have been wondering if it could be even simpler.

[image: Fanout Line Driver]

Image source: [Pulse Research Lab - PRL-414B - 1:4 TTL/CMOS Fanout Buffer and Line Driver](https://www.pulseresearchlab.com/products/prl-414b?variant=40597758115955#tab2)

IF SO, since the output of a 555 timer is buffered, would I even need the first buffer on the left? Input and output resistors? 1K on the input? Suggestions?

OR will the hex buffer chip not accomplish what I want it to?

(Sorry about the previous version of this question. I was just happy that I managed to include an image. I have trouble with this site. I can't find a search function on it to save my life. And apparently I no longer get email prompts with regards to replies.)

Answer (score 0):

Yoo can probably connect the output of the 555 directly to your other circuits without an explicit distribution amplifier.

If you are dealing with actual audio signals, rather than the square waves that the 555 generates, then the CD4050 or other digital logic parts are not suitable - you would need op-amps or other analog circuits.

Comment: So, @Peter Bennett, I can do something like this with no buffers of any sort needed for extra 'juice'? Arrghhh! I did a drawing and I can't figure out how to insert it here. It shows the output from pin-3 of the 555 timer circuit going to a mixing board and also going to an octave-up circuit and to a frequency divider circuit (both in parallel), and the outputs of those circuits then going to the mixing board, as well. Much like the configuration of the image above—without any of the components.